# Prefix and suffix every word in a line for all lines

Tags: linux, text-processing

Prefix and suffix every word in a line for all lines in a file called VP.log

```
E1 /opt/app/db/ggs/12.1.2.1.10/dirdat/fo   DF  abc-ctr-vip.ksc2.cci.com
```

should become

```
'E1' '/opt/app/db/ggs/12.1.2.1.10/dirdat/fo'   'DF'  'abc-ctr-vip.cci.com'
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `sed`, wrap each sequence of non-blank characters:

```
$ sed -E "s/[^[:blank:]]+/'&'/g" VP.log 
'E1' '/opt/app/db/ggs/12.1.2.1.10/dirdat/fo'   'DF'  'abc-ctr-vip.ksc2.cci.com'
```

Comment: Thank you, it's working.